# Search for words with the letter ü in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I do a LIKE search in MS SQL I want to get all Günter's when I search for Gunter. I'm using the Finnish_Swedish collation and they treat them as different characters. Anyone have a tip?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Contains Search and German Umlaut on SQL Server 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192525/t-sql-contains-search-and-german-umlaut-on-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: I assume you want to find it also with `Guenter` which would be the correct way to remove umlauts.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think this is a duplicate of the question above. Swedish is not German and the request is different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Column LIKE '%G[uü]nter%'
```

That will search for one of the 2 versions of `u`

Comment: No, shouldn't be worse than a "standard" like.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you specified an accent sensitive collation for your server or database.
To do an accent insensitive select, you can explicitly specify a [collation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx).
However, it seems you have chosen the wrong collation for your purpose.

Comment: No, I'm using Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI. ü is not treated as an accent.

Comment: You're right, didn't know that. In Latin1_General_CI_AI it would work.  
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/415171/finnish-swedish-collation-does-not-handle-sorting-correctly suggests using Sami_Sweden_Finland_100 instead.

Comment: Yes, that will solve this problem, but in Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI y and u is the same wish I also want. Can't have both I guess.